# Application cache in Google Chrome

Tags: caching, google-chrome, manifest

I have:

```
<html manifest="cache.manifest">
```

in beep.htm.  And I have:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# rev 20111128
beep.js
beep.htm
/Library/jQuery/jQuery.js
```

In my cache.manifest file.

In Google Chrome, under Resources, Application Cache, it says "No Application Cache Information available".

Q: Is the cache.manifest file used for the Application Cache, or is the Application cache something different?

Can I see what's actually loaded from the cache.manifest file, just to verify that it's working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/

> .appcache is now the recommended file extension for cache manifests.
>   Please ensure you update your filename, manifest attribute on the html
>   element and set the correct mime-type in your server config.

but I am still seeing No App Cache information available when I go see Resources.
If you've found a way out, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to get this one. I had set the manifest to cache a file which wasn't present on the server. (favicon.ico, of all things.) The whole thing failed.

One I removed that, manifest loads and "No Application Cache Information available" instead shows the cache.